# Error running Rust project with workspaces using cargo-watch and docker compose

Tags: docker, rust, docker-compose, dockerfile, rust-cargo

I'm trying to setup development environment for Rust project with workspaces using `cargo-watch` and `docker-compose`. There are my configs:

Main `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[workspace]
resolver = "2"

members = [
    "lib_bot",
]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  lib_bot:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: lib_bot
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - cargo_registry_lib_bot:/usr/local/cargo/registry
      - ./lib_bot/src:/app/lib_bot/src
      - ./lib_bot/Cargo.toml:/app/lib_bot/Cargo.toml
      - ./target:/app/target
      - ./Cargo.lock:/app/Cargo.lock
      - ./Cargo.toml:/app/Cargo.toml

volumes:
  cargo_registry_lib_bot: {}
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM rust:1.76.0

# Install required dependencies to solve the problem "linking with `cc` failed"
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        libssl-dev \
        pkg-config \
        libclang-dev \
        llvm-dev \
        && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app

# Install cargo-watch
RUN cargo install cargo-watch

COPY ./Cargo.lock ./Cargo.lock
COPY ./Cargo.toml ./Cargo.toml

COPY ./lib_bot/src ./librium_bot/src
COPY ./lib_bot/Cargo.toml ./lib_bot/Cargo.toml

RUN cargo clean
RUN cargo build

CMD ["cargo", "watch", "-x", "run", "-p", "lib_bot"]
```

But this configs lead new similar error while recompile:

```
error: could not write output to /app/target/debug/deps/lib_bot-ba0cae4639db1016.2s99ixstsj1t5hnk.rcgu.o: No such file or directory
```

As you see, I'm linked target folder with local folder, and when I checked it, all folders are exists, but error is happening time by time. Sometime, everything compiled correctly.

If I run it outside docker container, on MacOS, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I found an answer!

This is a problem because my local system is MacOS and the docker container is Linux, and when I linked the `target` folder, it seems that the local MacOS is trying to change the `target` folder in parallel (not sure why).

So, fix looks like this change in `docker-compose.yml` file:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  lib_bot:
    build:
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    container_name: lib_bot
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - cargo_registry_lib_bot:/usr/local/cargo/registry
      - ./lib_bot/src:/app/lib_bot/src
      - ./lib_bot/Cargo.toml:/app/lib_bot/Cargo.toml
      - /app/target
      - ./Cargo.lock:/app/Cargo.lock
      - ./Cargo.toml:/app/Cargo.toml

volumes:
  cargo_registry_lib_bot: {}
```

No local folder linked with `target` folder any more and it is solved the problem